# Should the word 'District' be capitalized in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

Sentence 1: The trip took us out of the **District** on the Maryland side as we headed west through picturesque rolling hills and farm lands. (note shouldn't district be lowercased-if not why not..please?)

Answer (score 1):

"District" here refers to the [District of Columbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.) which is a proper noun and therefore must be capitalized. You can see this usage in other place names, for example "the City" referring to New York City or the City of London.

"The district" referring to a general area would be an improper noun and would not be capitalized.

Comment: Sometimes we have to distinguish between the city of London and the City of London.